# how can i replace the text/title of a column on dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

dataset_poste.to_csv("dataset_poste_data.csv")
dataset_poste = pd.DataFrame(dataset_poste)

dataset_poste = dataset_poste.drop(["Open", "High", "Low", "Adj Close", "Volume"], axis=1)
dataset_poste = dataset_poste.replace("Close" , "Poste_close")
dataset_poste.tail()

the code doesn't work for me, no error, but it doesn't change the title of my column

i don't really how to do it, please, help me

Answer (score 0):

If understand the question correctly, you are trying to rename one column in the dataframe, you can do it as follows:

```
df.rename(columns={"Close": "Poste_close"}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks guys, the first code works for me.
have a nice days.
happy cristhmaxs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, if your dataframe have only one column

You can do this:

```
dataset_poste.columns = ['Poste_close']
```

And if you have other columns to rename:

```
dataset_poste.columns = ['Poste_close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume']
```

Remember: Always in dataframe column order

Comment: thanks mate, the code works quite good for me!! 
merry cristhmaxs!!